# Exclusion in sonar property file also in Analysis properties

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops

How to add exclusions in sonar "Analysis properties" in jenkins even exclusion available in sonar property file.

We have exclusions in property file, and we added exclusion in "Analysis properties" in jenkins. But while scanning it is excluding only the files given in "Analysis properties", but not from the property file.

we want the exclusion given both in Property file as well as from the "Analysis properties" field.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties are not cumulative. As described at the top of [this page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters), there is a fallback structure and the first-found value is the one that's used from this order of checking:

- command line
- properties file
- project-level properties defined in the UI
- global-level properties

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to set exclusions in property file commonly for few jobs and also I want to append few more exclusions in "Analysis Parameter" based on job requirements in Jenkins.